# How can I randomize controls when they are added

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, random, htmlgenericcontrol

I have three ul like this :

```
<ul id="column3" class="column" runat="server"> </ul>

<ul id="column4" class="column" runat="server"> </ul>


<ul id="column5" class="column" runat="server"> </ul>
```

I wanna to add listitems to them randomly:

```
 HtmlGenericControl listItem1 = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
 listItem1.Attributes.Add("class", colors[RandString.Next(0, colors.Length -1)]);
 column3.Controls.Add(listItem1); //here  i wanna to randomize the ul(column3,column4,column5) like i do with the colors
```

How to do something like that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put those ul in an array

```
var uls = new[] { column3, column4, column5 };
```

and then pick a random one:

```
var ul = uls[random.Next(0, uls.Length)];
ul.Controls.Add(listItem1);
```

Notice that you don't need `uls.Length - 1` because the upper bound is exclusive in the [Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean randomize the ul's content, you could simply use the color's int value as the random definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lists = new [] { column3, column4, column5 };
Random rand = new Random();
for ( int n = 0; n < 10; n++ )
{
   HtmlGenericControl listItem1 = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
   listItem1.Attributes.Add("class", colors[RandString.Next(0, colors.Length -1)]);
   lists[rand.Next(0,lists.Count)].Controls.Add(listItem1);
}
```